# Add JPanel inside of a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

I created a window with 5 panels and a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) but then had trouble drawing graphics.

I'm unsure of how to actually put that into a [`BorderLayout.CENTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER) because it doesn't seem to be the same way as before when I just made a `new JPanel`.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this?

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
      
public class GameScene2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mainGameScene();
            }
        });
    }
         
    private static void mainGameScene() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("This is my first game :o");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(new mainGamePanel());
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
      
class mainGamePanel extends JPanel {

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1280, 720);
    }
         
    public void paintComponent(Graphics pencil) {
        super.paintComponent(pencil);
        pencil.drawString("Boo", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

add it to the frame like so.

Here is a full link to explain how use use Borderlayout:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

This explains how to add it to a panel:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

**EDIT**:

So originally you have 
window.add(new mainGamePanel());

instead try

```
mainGamePanel p = new mainGamePanel();
p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
window.add(p);
```

Comment: I apologise but I'm not sure if I follow.
That's how I was doing it before, but with this code I created the panel by extending a method to JPanel.
So my JPanel isn't an object, is it? or if it is, how do I call it when putting it into a borderlayout?

Comment: That should set your panel to border layout

Comment: Wow that was like 4 questions at once

Comment: You might want to make a new post/ question page as those questions are something else entirely